# How to store value in dropdown using string array?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver and i want to get dropdown value but i am unable to do it. below is my code...

```
// this Array stores all dropdown element IDs..

String arrList[] = new String[] { "cmplStage", "risk", "frequency",
                    "nature", "complType", "locselect", "unitselect",
                    "department", "companyId" };

// this array stores dropdown values..
String strValue[] = new String[] { "Due", "A", "MONTHLY",
                    "Finance", "Filling & Payments", "Production", "", "HRM",
                    "TATA Group" };

        Select drop_down_select;
        for (String str_drop_box : arrList) {
            drop_down_select = new Select(
                    user_login_details.driver.findElement(By
                            .id(str_drop_box)));
            for (String value : strValue) {
                drop_down_select.selectByValue(value);
            }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
```

please help me out?...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you have an array of IDs and an array of values?

Comment: So, you have many combo boxes on a page whose ids are stored in arrList[]? And you want to select the value in those combo boxes and those values should be read from strValue[]? It is not clear what you want to do and why. You say "i want to **get** dropdown value" in the question, but your code is to **select** a value in the combo box. Please be clear and specific about your requirement and state the minimum required information about the context in order to answer the question.

Comment: I just want to select values on respective drop down according to their ids. I have multiple drop downs in my webpage.

Comment: Can you provide the html?

Answer (score 0):

In C# the code looks like:

```
var dropDown = new SelectElement(this.browser.FindElement(By.Name("country")).SelectByText(clientInfo.Country);
dropDown.SelectByText("Bulgaria");
var text = dropDown.SelectedOption.Text;
```